# How to toggle specific multiple columns in a specific table in HTML using jQuery nth child selector?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, show-hide

I have a webpage where I show multiple tables.
I would like to toggle the visibility of some columns of one specific table.
I started using :

```
$(document).on("change","#includePaths",function() {
    $("td:nth-child(3)").toggle();
});
```

when I had only one table.

Two questions :

1. How to modify the above code so it adresses only one table (which is in `<div id="mytable">...</div>`) ?
2. How to modify the above code so it toggles multiple columns based on a regex match on the table headers ?

Comment: 1. `$('#mytable td:nth-child(3)').toggle()` 2. why would you use regex if you know the table column number?

Comment: That's the point. I don't know it anymore. And I want to hide multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to point number 1 though. it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try this:

```
var regex_to_hide = /cool.*regex/;

$(document).on("change", "#includePaths", function() {
  var columnsToHide = new Array();

  // I'm assuming #includePaths is the table
  // If not - replace "this" with the right selector for your table  

  // Test headers to see what we need to hide
  $("#mytable").find("th").each(function(i, th) {
      if (regex_to_hide.test($(th).html())) {
          columnsToHide.push(i);
      }
  });

  // Hide numbered columns
  for(i = 0; i < columnsToHide.lenght; i++) {
    $("#mytable").find("td:nth-child(" + columnsToHide[i] + ")").toggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Exactly what I needed. I have made some edits on your answer to exactly match what I was asking though.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need some thing like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VjJpe/ You need to follow the markup. I have provided only one table structure but the same markup will do the job with multiple table too.

```
    <table border="1" class="toggling_table">
    <th class="catcher" data-togglerid="1">Click to toggle</th>
    <th>No Click</th>
    <th class="catcher" data-togglerid="3">Click to toggle</th>
    <tr>
    <td class="toggler_1" >it will toggle</td>
    <td >it will not toggle</td>
    <td class="toggler_3">it will toggle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="toggler_1" >it will toggle</td>
    <td >it will not toggle</td>
    <td class="toggler_3">it will toggle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="toggler_1" >it will toggle</td>
    <td >it will not toggle</td>
    <td class="toggler_3">it will toggle</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $(".toggling_table").on("click", ".catcher", function(){
    var id  = $(this).data("togglerid");
    alert(id);
    $(".toggler_"+id).toggle();
    }); 
    });
    </script>
```